# Unsolicited Chrome redirections to scam websites

Tags: security

When I am using Chrome browser on my Samsung Galaxy S8 (Android 7.0, kernel version is 4.4.13-11814589) sometimes when I click on a link or just read a website suddenly I am redirected to scammy websites, like premium.android-sales.com, which offers me some shady OS updates. See the picture (sorry, the redirect is in Polish):

[image: Scammy website]

I don't know if the issue persists with other browsers. However, it was also an issue with my good old Xperia Z3 Compact that used Android 6. The issue is usually encountered when I browse [following site](http://gazeta.pl) (webportal of biggest Polish newspaper, so I doubt the scam comes directly from them).

I have found people suggesting that my router's DNS was somehow altered, however the issue happens also when I am outside of my router's range on a cellular network. Could it be the case that some rogue ad is at fault or is it a problem with my phone? How can it be mitigated?

Comment: Same thing started to happen to me from onet.pl to premium.android-sales.com. Coincidentally on the same hardware and Chrome, but accessing from abroad, so I guess it's rather a rogue ad.